# jekyll 3.3.1 | Error: bundler

Tags: jekyll

```
$ gem install jekyll
$ jekyll new my-awesome-site
New jekyll site installed in /home/root/blog/Jekyll/my-awesome-site. 
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have bundler or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- bundler' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  bundler
```

Answer (score 5):

Like you can read in [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/), you've missed `bundler` in `gem install jekyll bundler`.

So : `gem install bundler` and everything will be ok.